# Sufficient conditions on $f_n\longrightarrow f$ so that $\hat{f_n}\longrightarrow\hat f$ in $L^1$ sense

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a Schwartz function, and suppose $(f_n)_n\subset\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}$ is such that $f_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}f$ in the $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ norm.

Is it true that then, $\hat{f_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\hat{f}$ in the $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ sense as well? (Here $\hat f$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$.)

[EDIT: it appears to be false in general, as necessary conditions for $\hat{f_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\hat{f}$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ include that $(f_n)_n$ converge uniformly to $f$. What would be sufficient conditions to make that happens, if there are any?]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

If $\hat{f_n}\to \hat f$ in $L^1$, then
$$f_n(0)=\int_{\mathbb R}\hat{f_n}\to \int_{\mathbb R}\hat f=f(0).$$ Thus it suffices to find $f_n$ and $f$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ but not pointwise to construct a counterexample. I leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks! Did not think of that, because the functions $f_n$ I am dealing with are $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, and $f$ is Schwartz. In other word, the sequence $f_n$ can be chosen to converge to $f$ in the $L^1$ sense *and* in the pointwise sense. I should have mentionned that in the original post. Does is make the claim true or is it still not sufficient?

Comment: @johnmad if $\hat f_n\to\hat f$ in $L^1,$ then $f_n\to f$ not only pointwise but uniformly. Thus it suffices to find $f_n\in C_c^\infty$ such that $\|f_n\|_1\to0$ but $\|f_n\|_\infty=1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval ah, I see now. Thanks a lot. I indeed cannot make the extra assumption that $(f_n) _n$ converges uniformly to $f$ by its very definition. It was an (yet again) unsuccessful attempt at proving https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695035/int-hatf-g-0-for-all-test-functions-f-implies-g-0.

Comment: @AnneBauval I was wondering, would it be sufficient if additionaly $(f_n)_n$ were to converge uniformly to $f$? I feel that it would still not be sufficient but cannot see why. In general, what would be sufficient conditions on the convergence of $(f_n)_n$ to $f$ to make $(\hat{f_n})_n$ converge to $\hat{f}$, if there are any? Thanks a lot

Comment: John mad: Interesting question! I have the same feeling as you but no intuition about that. I would be happy if Pelota or @Koobe could answer you.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is equivalent to asking whether Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}$ is bounded from $L^1$ to $L^1$. We know it is bounded from $L^1$ to  $L^\infty$. But it is not bounded from $L^1$ to $L^1$. If it is bounded, by interpolation then it is bounded from $L^1$ to $L^p$ for all $p$, which is not possible.

It is useful to use scaling invariance to check the boundedness of an operator. If $\|\hat{f}\|_1\leq C\|f\|_1$ for all $f$ and some constant $C$. Then substituting $f$ by $f_{\lambda}(x):=f(\lambda x)$. Then you will get:

$$ \|\hat{f}\|_1\leq\lambda^{-d}C\|f\|_1
$$
($d$ is the dimension $\mathbb{R}^d$)
Letting $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$, then we have $f=0$.

Comment: Why was the question "equivalent to asking whether Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}$ is bounded from $L^1$ to $L^1$"?

Comment: Continuous = boundedness if you know functional analysis.

Comment: I know, but this does definitely not answer my question about the *equivalence* (one direction is obvious, the other one, which you are using, is much less elementary).

Comment: Yes not equivalent. But we can choose the Schwartz space with $L^1$ norm, but still a little different. His functions $f_n$ is smooth compactly supported.

Comment: This is not my main point. Even assuming $\forall f_n\in\mathcal S\quad[\|f_n\|_1\to0\implies\|\hat f_n\|_1\to0],$ how do you derive the existence of some $C$ such that $\forall f_n\in\mathcal S\quad\|\hat f_n\|_1\le C\|f_n\|_1?$

Comment: Given your assumption, $F$(Fourier transform) is continuous at zero by Cauchy. So For any $\epsilon=1$, there exists a $\delta$, such that $\|F(f)\|\leq 1$ for all $\|f\|\leq \delta$, then $$ \|F(f)\|=\|\frac{\|f\|}{\delta}F(\delta \frac{f}{\|f\|}) \|\leq \frac{1}{\delta}\|f\|. $$

Comment: Oh, so obvious and usual! shame on me! Thank you for your patience and for taking the time to type it.